# How to add check-box in jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am trying to add check-box using jquery datatable.
Here is my initialise function.

```
initialiseDataTable : function(){
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable({ bJQueryUI: true,
    "bPaginate": false,
   "bInfo": false,
   "bRetrieve":true,
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"})
   .makeEditable({
                  sUpdateURL: function(value, settings)
                              {
                                      return(value);
                              },
                              "aoColumns": [

                       {
                           type: 'checkbox',
                       },

                       {   indicator: 'Saving CSS Grade...',
                           tooltip: 'Click to select CSS Grade',
                           loadtext: 'loading...',
                           type: 'select',
                           onblur: 'submit',
                           data: "{'':'Please select...', 'A':'A','B':'B','C':'C'}"  
                       },

                       {  

                       },

                       { 

                       },
                       { 

                       }
       ]
              });

   },
```

But it is giving some type error as 
**TypeError: $.editable.types[settings.type] is undefined

var plugin   = $.editable.types[settings.type].plugin || function() { };**
What is wrong in this? How should I add check-box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to define your "checkbox" type before you init this type

```
$.editable.addInputType('checkbox', {
    element: function () {
        var input = $('<input type="checkbox">');
        $(this).append(input);
        return(input);
    },
    content: function (columnValue) {
        /* some actions here */
    }
});
```